# Multiple posts with one loop iteration

Tags: loop, query-posts

I want 3 post with one loop iteration, so I'm using `the_post()` to achieve this: (html removed)

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    the_title();
    the_post();
    the_title();
    the_post();
    the_title();

endwhile; ?>
```

The problem starts, if number of posts is not divisible by 3. For example, if I have 5 posts, than this loop will still try to display 6 of them, generating empty html. How can I work it out? Or maybe I'm trying to achieve this functionality the wrong way?

@edit:
Here is HTML I wanna output to clarify my question:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="span3">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Content</p>
</div>
<div class="span3">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Content</p>
</div>
<div class="span3">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Content</p>
</div>
 </div>

 <div class="row">
<div class="span3">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Content</p>
</div>
<div class="span3">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Content</p>
</div>
<div class="span3">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Content</p>
</div>
</div>
```

So I want to surround every 3 posts with `.row`.

Comment: In human terms, what are you *trying to accomplish*? **Note**: The `the_post()` template tag doesn't actually output the *post*; rather, it merely sets up the `$post` global, and all of the template tags that rely on the `$post` global (such as `the_title()`). So, it should only ever be called *once* inside the Loop.

Comment: @ChipBennett: I've posted clarification in original question. I know, that the_post() doesn't output anything, I'm just trying to find a hack for my problem.

Comment: RE: Your post edit: that's *code*. I'm looking for *human terms* to describe what you're trying to accomplish. Code is an *implementation*; whether that implementation is the correct approach or not depends on what you're ultimately trying to accomplish. **For example:** are you trying to display a *grid of posts from the same query*, or perhaps display *three posts from one query, followed by three posts from a different query* (such as set of featured posts, followed by a *different* set of featured posts)?

Comment: @ChipBennett One, custom post type query, I want to display them in a grid.

Comment: Instead of calling the_post three times, just add a counter to do whatever it is that you want to do to separate the three posts and stick it behind a modulo comparison. `if ($counter % 3 == 0) do stuff` sort of thing.

Comment: @Otto Yeah, thats a good idea. But still, if I have 5 posts, than `$counter % 3 != 0' in last iteration, and I won't close my `.row` div, am I right?

Comment: So, really, this is more of a HTML/CSS/PHP question? There are various solutions, but none are WordPress specific.

Comment: @ChipBennett I'd like to leave my CSS as it is, so if thats possible with WordPress/PHP only, than I'd love this kind of solution. Anyway, I will use my solution from my own answer below. Thanks.

Comment: smogg: The key there is to always close after the loop, then you can close it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, this question is **off-topic**, because the solution has nothing to do with WordPress. Outputting posts in a grid pattern is an **HTML/CSS** issue, and the best-practice solutions don't involve putting every three posts inside a separate containing `<div>`. Even so, you can do what you want to do, using PHP (which, technically speaking, *still* makes this question **off-topic**).

I would start by querying a number of posts divisible by 3, or else setting `posts_per_page` to a number divisible by 3. How you do that depends on whether you're calling a new `WP_Query()` for your custom-post type loop, or if you're filtering `pre_get_posts` to modify the default query. Either way, you would use the `posts_per_page` query argument.

Then, you can simply define a counter inside the loop, and use it to close/open DIVs as necessary:

```
<div class="row">
<?php
$counter = 1;
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    global $wp_query;
    the_title(); 
    the_content(); 
    if ( ( 0 == $counter % 3 ) && ( $counter != $wp_query->posts_per_page ) ) {
    ?>
</div><div class="row">
    <?php
    }
    $counter++;
endwhile; endif;
?>
</div>
```

The second part of the conditional ensures that you don't get an empty div after the last row.

Answer (score -1):

After posting this question, I've had the "eureka" moment and achieved it (probably the ugly way) by surrounding my html for every post with simple `if(get_the_title())`. So if title doesn't exist, than don't display anything. But I still think there is more pretty way of doing this.